# python: how to get an item from a set of custom class object

Tags: python, data-structures, set

```
class Folder:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.items = []
    
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other.name
```

Lets create some folders:

```
folder_1 = Folder('folder_1')
folder_1.items = ['a', 'b', 'c']


folder_2 = Folder('folder_2')
folder_3 = Folder('folder_3')

folders = set([folder_1, folder_2, folder_3])
```

Now what I want to do is to find a folder in a `folders` set and access its item property without changing the `folders` set.

```
folder_to_find = Folder('folder_1')
```

We can notice that `folder_to_find == folder_1` is `True` with a difference that `folder_1` has `items` property set and `folder_to_find` has not.

I can check `folder_to_find` like object exists in `folders` set with `in` operator but cannot get `folder_1` with the help of `folder_to_find` so that I can access `items` property of `folder_1` object.

My workaround would be to use python dictionary instead of set.

Still, is there any way we can achieve this with O(1)?

Comment: Dictionary looks good here, I would use it instead of set, you still get O(1) lookup and if the folder names you create would be the keys - you also achieve the uniqueness. If you want to use set here, you can, but Python unfortunately misses feature like LINQ in .NET. In C# for example you can do: `.Select(x => x.name == "folder_1")`. There is a custom Python library for that, but I guess it would be an overkill (I also don't remember its name). Therefore I suggest using the dict, otherwise this looks like a for loop to me, with a `break` statement

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `for` loop or `next` with generator expression

```
folder = next((folder for folder in folders if folder == folder_to_find), None)
```

`folder` is a reference for `folder_1`, you can get `folder_1` data and edit it

```
folder.items[0] = 1
print(folder_1.items) # [1, 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: This is also a good answer, but seeing that for the first time is a pain (at least for me). I would still suggest using a dictionary. But if you want a one-liner (not a two-liner like with dict), this would be the way to go

Comment: We get O(n) complexity this way. I want it to be O(1).

Comment: @dabljues well the OP ask specifically how to do that with `set`

Comment: True. But then, if you want O(1) - cuz you'll be doing this a lot, the dictionary is your friend

Comment: @wrufesh You can have it with O(1) only using dictionaries.